# VBA Excel use '-' when value is null

Tags: excel, vba

I am displaying data from a SQL query in Excel as follows:

ActiveCell.Offset(r, 1).Value = rs2.Fields("OTCSalesQTD").Value

When the returned value is NULL I would like to display '--' rather than an empty cell.  How can this be done in Excel VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a combination of [IIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) and [IsNull](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isnull.php), something like the below

```
ActiveCell.Offset(r, 1).Value = IIF(ISNULL(rs2.Fields("OTCSalesQTD").Value),"--", rs2.Fields("OTCSalesQTD").Value)
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.  I was using 'If' and didn't know about 'IIf'